# how to test that a variable is undefined or that an exception is raised in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, error-handling

In my model, I am dynamically setting scopes

```
  AccountType.all_valid_types.each do |type| # AccountType.all_valid_types returns an array from database
    scope type.downcase.pluralize.split(' ').join('_').to_sym, -> { where(account_type: type) }
  end
```

In my spec test, I am trying to test that the model scope exists for `all_valid_types` and that when a type is created, updated or deleted, the scope should adjust accordingly...

**Implementation:**

```
#account_type.rb:
after_save :reset_profile_scopes
after_destroy :reset_profile_scopes

def reset_profile_scopes
  #unset file
  Object.send(:remove_const, "Profile")

  #reload file
  load "profile.rb"
end
```

**RSpec Test:**

```
describe "Dynamism" do
  it "should ensure that the profile.rb file (Profile class) gets reloaded after each create, update, and destroy" do
    Profile.connection #hack to simulate profile load already
    account_type = FactoryGirl.create(:account_type)
    expect(Profile.send(account_type.name.pluralize)).to be_an(ActiveRecord::Relation)
    name = Faker::Lorem.word
    account_type.update_attribute(:name, name)
    expect(Profile.send(name.pluralize)).to be_an(ActiveRecord::Relation)
    account_type.destroy
    expect(Profile.send(name.pluralize)).to raise_error
  end
end
```

All is working up to the line `expect(Profile.send(name.pluralize)).to raise_error`.

I know I expect it to throw an error, but how do I write the spec so that it passes with the error without throwing an error? ( Hope this is not confusing )

In other words, what RSpec syntax can I use to `expect an error/exception`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I had to guess:

```
expect(Profile.send(name.pluralize)).to raise_error
```

to:

```
expect { Profile.send(name.pluralize) }.to raise_error
```

Comment: Smooth man, very smooth. when I tried with: `expect { Profile.send(name.pluralize) }.to raise_error`, it passed but I got  a warning to provide the type of error. `expect { Profile.send(name.pluralize) }.to raise_error(WhateverError)` raised no warning however. Thank you.